# Showing 404 error page in crud examplewith CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter. I have followed the tutorial to create a crud system. 
http://www.expertphp.in/article/php-codeigniter-3-basic-crud-operation-with-mysql-database-with-example

I am using Linux Mint system. I have done all permission related things. Still i am getting 404 error page. when i go to

http://localhost/codeign/myapp/products

Here i made the products controller like this

```
class Products extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ProductsModel'); 
    }

    public function index() 
    {
        $Products = new ProductsModel;
        $data['data'] = $Products->get_poducts();
        $this->load->view('includes/header');       
        $this->load->view('products/list',$data);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }
```

Still i am getting 404 Not found page. can i know the fault i have done ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you set base url in your config file?

Comment: Yes, It is like " http://localhost/codeign/myapp".

Comment: Change with: $config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/codeign/myapp'; and in route.php set your default controller: $route['default_controller'] = 'your_def_controller;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this in .htaccess in your app directory (in same level to applications) and will works :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```